# Java - JApplet does not draw graph - May have to do with pixels and scaling

Tags: java, swing, graphics, applet, japplet

I am creating a derivative calculator in which the user enters the degree of their polynomial and then enters the coefficients of each term. The calculator displays the resulting derivative on an applet window as well as a graph of the original function.

Here is the graphing class.

```
package beta;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class GraphingCalc extends JApplet
{
    public void drawAxes(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

        Line2D.Double yaxis = new Line2D.Double(200, 400, 200, 0);
        Line2D.Double xaxis = new Line2D.Double(0, 200, 400, 200);
        g2.draw(yaxis);
        g2.draw(xaxis);

        for (int i = 0; i<=20; i++)
        {
            Line2D.Double ytick = new Line2D.Double(197, 400 - i * 20, 203, 400 - i * 20);
            Line2D.Double xtick = new Line2D.Double(400 - i * 20, 203, 400 - i * 20, 197);
            g2.draw(ytick);
            g2.draw(xtick);
        }
    }

    public void drawFunction(Graphics g, List<Double> l)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

        double x1 = 0;
        double y1 = 0;
        double x2 = 0;
        double y2 = 0;
        int size = l.size();

        for (double x = -10; x <= 10; x += 0.2)
        {
            x1 = x;
            for (int d = size-1; d>=0; d--)
            {
                y1 += l.get(d) * Math.pow(x1, d);
            }
            Point2D.Double first = new Point2D.Double(20 * x1 + 200, -20 * y1 + 200);

            x2 = x1 + 0.2;
            for (int d = size-1; d>=0; d--)
            {
                y2 += l.get(d) * Math.pow(x2, d);
            }
            Point2D.Double second = new Point2D.Double(20 * x2 + 200, -20 * y2 + 200);

            Line2D.Double line = new Line2D.Double(first, second);
            g2.draw(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the derivative calculation class. The only relevant part is when I get the list of coefficients from the user `coeffList`

```
package beta;

import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DerivativeCalculator 
{
    public DerivativeCalculator()
    {
        String d = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the degree of your polynomial: ");
        String v = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the x value "
                + "at which you want to take the derivative: ");

        degree = Integer.parseInt(d);
        value = Double.parseDouble(v);

        coeffList = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= degree; i++)
        {
            String console = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the coefficient of the "
                    + "x^" + i + " term.");
            Double coeff = Double.parseDouble(console);

            coeffList.add(coeff);
        }

    }
    public double calc()
    {
        double dx = 0.00001;

        double x1 = value;
        double y1 = 0;
        for (int d = degree; d >= 0; d--)
        {
            y1 += coeffList.get(d) * Math.pow(x1, d);
        }

        double x2 = x1 + dx;
        double y2 = 0;
        for (int d = degree; d >= 0; d--)
        {
            y2 += coeffList.get(d) * Math.pow(x2, d);
        }

        double slope = (y2 - y1)/ (x2 - x1);

        DecimalFormat round = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
        round.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);

        return Double.valueOf(round.format(slope));
    }

    public String getEquation()
    {
        String equation = "";
        for (int d = degree; d >= 1; d--)
        {
            equation = equation + String.valueOf(coeffList.get(d)) + "x^" + String.valueOf(d) + " + ";
        }
        equation = equation + String.valueOf(coeffList.get(0)) + "x^" + String.valueOf(0);
        return equation;
    }

    public String getValue()
    {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }

    public List<Double> getCoeff()
    {
        return coeffList;
    }
    private int degree;
    private double value;
    private List<Double> coeffList;

}
```

Lastly, this is the test class which incorporates the two previous classes.

```
package beta;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DerivativeCalculatorTest extends JApplet
{
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        setSize(800,800);

        DerivativeCalculator myDerivCalc = new DerivativeCalculator();
        g2.drawString(String.valueOf(myDerivCalc.calc()), 10, 100);
        g2.drawString(myDerivCalc.getEquation(), 10, 40);
        g2.drawString(myDerivCalc.getValue(), 10, 70);

        GraphingCalc myGrapher = new GraphingCalc();
        myGrapher.drawAxes(g2);
        myGrapher.drawFunction(g2, myDerivCalc.getCoeff());
    }

}
```

The applet runs, displays all the derivative information correctly, but the function graph does not draw correctly. For example when I input x + 5, the applet draws a bunch of individual straight lines, but they are clustered in the shape of a parabola.

I immediately suspect that it has to do with the way I draw the graph. I actually make a bunch of short lines with length 0.2.

```
for (double x = -10; x <= 10; x += 0.2)
            {
                x1 = x;
                for (int d = size-1; d>=0; d--)
                {
                    y1 += l.get(d) * Math.pow(x1, d);
                }
                Point2D.Double first = new Point2D.Double(20 * x1 + 200, -20 * y1 + 200);

                x2 = x1 + 0.2;
                for (int d = size-1; d>=0; d--)
                {
                    y2 += l.get(d) * Math.pow(x2, d);
                }
                Point2D.Double second = new Point2D.Double(20 * x2 + 200, -20 * y2 + 200);

                Line2D.Double line = new Line2D.Double(first, second);
                g2.draw(line);
            }
```

What is the problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 3) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Answer (score 4):

Some Points:

Your `GraphingCalc` class should not `extends` the `JApplet` and also for drawing lines you don't need to create some `Line2D` objects and then draw them. You can simply call `drawLine` method:

```
package beta;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.List;

public class GraphingCalc
{
    public void drawAxes(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

        g2.drawLine(200, 400, 200, 0);
        g2.drawLine(0, 200, 400, 200);

        for (int i = 0; i<=20; i++)
        {
            g2.drawLine(197, 400 - i * 20, 203, 400 - i * 20);
            g2.drawLine(400 - i * 20, 203, 400 - i * 20, 197);
        }
    }

    public void drawFunction(Graphics g, List<Double> l)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

        double x1 = 0;
        double y1 = 0;
        double x2 = 0;
        double y2 = 0;
        int size = l.size();

        for (double x = -10; x <= 10; x += 0.2)
        {
            x1 = x;
            for (int d = size-1; d>=0; d--)
            {
                y1 += l.get(d) * Math.pow(x1, d);
            }

            x2 = x1 + 0.2;
            for (int d = size-1; d>=0; d--)
            {
                y2 += l.get(d) * Math.pow(x2, d);
            }

            g2.drawLine((int)x1, (int)y1, (int)x2, (int)y2);
        }
    }
}
```

This way your program shows both axis and ticks. Also for a Polynomial of degree 1 it draws a line, but somehow I can tell it's not drawing the polynomial correctly. Maybe you want to correct some calculations. As you can see a simple polynomial of degree one with these coefficients should not be look like this:

[image]
Good Luck.